# Extracting a number with dot and comma using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, extract

I've read a lot of pages trying to explain me how to use the `regex` for Python but I still don't get it at all. Even the [regex wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) and the [re documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) couldn't help me at all. I'm still kind of confused :P

I have the following string:

```
string = "|C195|1|Base de Cálculo ST: 2.608,24 - Valor da ST: 163,66|"
```

I'm trying to extract only the `2.608,24` and `163,66` using:

```
st_values = re.findall("\d+[,.]\d+", string)
```

However, the output of my `print st_values` is:

```
['2.608','163,66']
```

Instead, I expect it to be

```
['2.608,24','163,66']
```

I don't want

```
['195', '1', '2.608,24','163,66']
```

So, how can I use the alphabet soup of regex parameters to extract them that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
\b\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d+\b
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dN6lL6/2)

And here is an [IDEONE code demo](http://ideone.com/sP78ct):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\b\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d+\b')
test_str = "|C195|1|Base de Cálculo ST: 2.608,24 - Valor da ST: 2.608.234,24 12.608.234,24\n  163,66|\nd2.608.234,24\n2.60d8.23d4,24"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

Comment: yout answer fits my data too, but since his way is 'cleaner' i found it easier to read and understand, but thanks anyway!!

Comment: @Pardoido: But what if you have `2.600.100,34`?  Have a [look here](https://regex101.com/r/aJ1qT4/3) - it will fail. `\b` is a word boundary. You can remove them if you also want to match the digits enclosed into word characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (This regex also assumes that strings like`1,23` is matched.)-

```
>>> re.findall("\d+(?:\.\d+)?,\d+", string)
['2.608,24', '163,66']
```

[Regex demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/aJ1qT4/1)

Comment: @Tushar hmm why should it? It doesn't have the comma notation that OP asks for

Comment: it fits prefectly in my data.. really thanks, @Kamehameha

Comment: @Kamehameha, take a look at stribizhev comment in the accepted answer, maybe it will help you too..

Answer (score 1):

if you want to extract the numbers from the second last column/field, you can do something like:

```
 In: re.findall(r"[0-9,.]+",string.split('|')[-2])      
Out: ['2.608,24', '163,66']
```

Otherwise, if you do it only with regex, and there was similar numbers in other column, you have problem to filter them out.